# Reduce spacing between logo and search field (WordPress Twenty Eleven)

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I am trying to reduce the spacing between the search bar and logo (http://cultsotters.org.uk), using the child theme of Twenty Eleven.

As the spacing is too large.

Tried reducing the size of the banner image, although that doesn't seem to help

Any help, much appreciated.

Css Code:

```
#branding {border:none;}
#branding {background: #ffff88; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff88 0%, #ffff88 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffff88), color-stop(100%,#ffff88)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff88 0%,#ffff88 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff88 0%,#ffff88 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff88 0%,#ffff88 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffff88 0%,#ffff88 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff88', endColorstr='#ffff88',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
margin:none;
}
/* logo above site title */
#site-title a {
    background: url('http://www.cultsotters.org.uk/images/cults_otters_black.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;
    display: block;
   max-height: 100px;

padding-top:70px;
  text-align: center;
   width: auto;
line-height:30px;
font-size:30px;
}
#branding hgroup {
text-align: center; display: inline; margin:0; align:center;}
#site-title, #site-description {
    margin: ; text-align: center; 
    }
#site-title > span > a {
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

HTMl Code:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
            <hgroup>
                <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span></h1>
                <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </hgroup>

            <?php
                // Check to see if the header image has been removed
                $header_image = get_header_image();
                if ( $header_image ) :
                    // Compatibility with versions of WordPress prior to 3.4.
                    if ( function_exists( 'get_custom_header' ) ) {
                        /*
                         * We need to figure out what the minimum width should be for our featured image.
                         * This result would be the suggested width if the theme were to implement flexible widths.
                         */
                        $header_image_width = get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'width' );
                    } else {
                        $header_image_width = HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH;
                    }
                    ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    /*
                     * The header image.
                     * Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                     */
                    if ( is_singular() && has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( $header_image_width, $header_image_width ) ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= $header_image_width ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else :
                        // Compatibility with versions of WordPress prior to 3.4.
                        if ( function_exists( 'get_custom_header' ) ) {
                            $header_image_width  = get_custom_header()->width;
                            $header_image_height = get_custom_header()->height;
                        } else {
                            $header_image_width  = HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH;
                            $header_image_height = HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
                        }
                        ?>
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo $header_image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $header_image_height; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>

            <?php
                // Has the text been hidden?
                if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) :
            ?>
                <div class="only-search<?php if ( $header_image ) : ?> with-image<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php
                else :
            ?>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php if ( ! is_singular() ) : ?>
                    <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID #site-title has a lot of padding set at the top. If you reduce that it will tighten up the space.

Try this:

```
#site-title {
    padding: 2.306em 0 0;
}
```

Comment: The padding is there so the logo and the text do not overlap each other.

Comment: Ok, fixed by putting it at the end of the css file. Thanks Vectorloft for your help.